# VB.net: Send Live Data to Serial Port

Tags: vb.net, serial-port, send

I'm totally stuck at how to send the live data (continuously automatically change value) to serial port. For example in this code, i try to send 2 data together with time. I manage to send them out but they are not updated value. it is not continuously updated.
See Private Sub Button2_Click:

```
'------------------------------------------------
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    'combined data = data1 + data2 + data3 + .....
    'Space is to allow space in between data
    RichTextBox1.Text = BasicLabel1.Text & Space(8) & BasicLabel2.Text & Space(8) & DateAndTime.TimeString
    SerialPort1.Write(RichTextBox1.Text & vbCr) 'concatenate with \n

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

i finally found the solution:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    RichTextBox1.Text = BasicLabel1.Text & Space(8) & BasicLabel2.Text & Space(8) & DateAndTime.Now.ToString
    If SerialPort1.IsOpen Then
        SerialPort1.Write(RichTextBox1.Text + vbCr)
        Me.Refresh()
    End If

End Sub
```